# Display Store Products in Row from MySQL table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck - I'm pulling store items from a MySQL table for an online store. The query returns the items. Normally, I would I use the following, which lists each product in a separate row:

```
<table>
<?php
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($productListResults)){
?>
<tr align="left">
<td><b><?php echo $rows['manufacturer']; ?> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

**However**, now, I would like to display 3-4 products per row and then continue the rest of the products on the next row. I've included an example below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
PRODUCT1       PRODUCT2       PRODUCT3

PRODUCT4       PRODUCT5       PRODUCT6

PRODUCT7       PRODUCT8       PRODUCT9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <table>
    <tr>

<?php
$split=0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($productListResults)){
   echo '<td><strong>'.$rows['manufacturer'].'</strong></td>';  
       $split++;   
       if ($split%3==0){
       echo '</tr><tr>';
        }

     } ';
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The easiest way to do this would likely be to use a variable to keep track of how many you've already printed in this row.

The pseudocode would look something like:

```
let $i = 0
for each result from the database:
    if $i is equal to 0:
        echo the stuff that's needed to start a row (<tr>, etc.)

    print out the stuff needed for a cell in the table, based on $row
    increment $i by 1

    if $i is equal to 3:
        echo the stuff that's needed to end a row (</tr>, etc.)

repeat the process if you still have more rows to print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
   <?php
   $rows = mysql_fetch_array($productListResults);
   $columns = 3
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
   ?>
      <?php if ($i % $columns == 0): ?>
         <tr align="left">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <td><b><?php echo $rows[$i]['manufacturer']; ?></b></td>
      <?php if ($i % $columns == ($columns - 1) || $i == count($rows) - 1): ?>
         </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Please let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to go about this.  A PHP way is like this:

```
<table><tr>
<?php $i = 0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($productListResults)) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['manufacturer']; ?></td>
<?php if (0 == ++$i % 3) { ?>  
        </tr><tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tr></table>
```

This approach starts out with a row, then starts looping and adding columns.  The row is stopped when the column count is an integer divisor of the count we want.  (The "3" in "$i % 3".)

This approach is not ideal.  Note that it can result in an empty  in a particular edge case.  Fixing that is a reader exercise.

That said, perhaps you would like to consider doing this in CSS.  That way, you can output a straight list, then use presentation to adjust the flow to meet your needs.  Here's an easy intro on doing that: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/